# How to block non-friends from commenting on my Facebook photos?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I posted a photo and tagged a friend. Her friend (whom I don't know) commented on it. I don't like that non-friends can somehow comment on my photos just because they are friends with my friend. Is there a way to block (at least) the comment part? Do I have to un-tag my friend to disallow comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you post to "Friends" or more (including "Friends of Friends" or "Public"), then the friends of the people that are tagged will also be able to see, like, and comment on your post.

> [When I tag someone in a photo or post, who can see it?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=240051956039320#When-I-tag-someone-in-a-photo-or-post,-who-can-see-it?)
>
> When you tag someone, it may be visible to:
>
> 1. The audience you selected for your post.
> 2. Friends of the person you tagged (if the audience is set to Friends or more).
>
> People who can see your photo or post can also like or comment on it.

You can get around this by posting to a friend list instead.  If you create a friend list with all of your friends on it and post to that list (by entering the list name using the Custom setting), then you can post to all of your friends without automatically including the friends of the tagged people.  However when you add new friends you would need to remember to manually add them to that friend list.

Comment: Thank you!! Not only you understood my question, you also gave me the solution. (That sounds like how Google+ circle works.)

Answer (score 1):

You can control who you share with when posting each item separately. This is done through a dropdown list, as in this image:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to change the default setting of who you share with, you can do so from your Privacy Settings screen. It is accessed from the top right corner, near your profile name.

[image]

Selecting Friends in any of the above will exclude your friends' friends, meaning they will not be able to access the photos, no matter who is tagged.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, as I already have a custom setting that excludes even more people (friends only except a restricted list). FB hinted that the person can comment because she's friends with my friend who is tagged. I'm appalled that some of my own friends (the restricted ones) supposedly can't see the photo, but this person whom I do not know and aren't friends with can see and comment freely. Just wondering if it's because my friend is tagged so FB treat the photo as if it were hers too (i.e. HER friends can see and comment on MY photo.)

Answer (score 1):

I have found an option in Settings/Subscribers (translating from Russian here). It sais something like "Who can comment on you public posts". You can choose "Friends" there.